# AttributeError: 'FasterRcnn' object has no attribute 'inplace_batchnorm_update'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train a pretrained `"faster_rcnn_resnet101_kitti"` model for the tensorflow object detection API.

But everytime I try to run

```
 python3 train.py --logtostderr --train_dir='/training/' --pipeline_config_path='/training/faster_rcnn_resnet101_kitti.config'
```

I receive the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "train.py", line 167, in <module>
      tf.app.run()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist- packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
   File "train.py", line 163, in main
worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg/object_detection/trainer.py", line 211, in train
detection_model = create_model_fn()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 96, in build
add_summaries)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 272, in _build_faster_rcnn_model
frcnn_config.inplace_batchnorm_update)
AttributeError: 'FasterRcnn' object has no attribute 'inplace_batchnorm_update'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this error too, and for me it was because I had not [re-compiled my .proto-files](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#protobuf-compilation) after I pulled the last updates from the TF models repository.

To recompile (on Linux):

```
# From tensorflow/models/research/ folder
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

I assume that the failing code tries to read the attribute/field `inplace_batchnorm_update` from the faster rcnn config, which (assumable) does not exist in the older versions. I hope this helps you too.

My versions are: tensorflow-gpu 1.7.0 and have the TF models commit hash 77d3bbefeb33e89bfa1eee707151e5d794d1222b with message "Merge pull request #3888 from hsm207/patch-3 Fix typo".

#### Recompiling on Windows

I know from own experience that, compared to Windows, compiling many files as above is easy in Linux as a one-liner. For Windows, here is something to make the process less cumbersome:

In [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1934), [davemers0160](https://github.com/davemers0160) has shared 
a script for compiling on Windows.

Just save [this file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/files/1531808/run_protoc.txt) as a `.bat`-file:

```
@echo off 
setlocal
echo Searching for new .proto files...

for %%F in (object_detection\protos\*.proto) do (
    echo %%F
    protoc %%F --python_out=.
)

echo Complete!
```

Run that file from the same folder as mentioned above. As the question was in Linux, I've just added this to the bottom in case a Windows user come along to read this too.

Comment: Great thanks! the recompiling of the proto files solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after I updated the models repository.
I re-compiled `.proto` files, but it still has the error.

According to the log:

```
File "/home/duane/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 164, in _build_ssd_model
inplace_batchnorm_update=ssd_config.inplace_batchnorm_update)
```

**I think maybe it caused by the version of object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg is too old , So I re-installed `models/research/setup.py`:**

```
# Form /models/research/ 
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Then it has no error.

**NOTE: I did re-compile `.proto` files before I re-install setup.py.**
The more details you can see [#3968](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3968)

Hope this can help you.